# Каждый элемент списка кодировать в Unicode

Tags: python

Хочу каждый элемент списка перевести в символы Unicode, но ничего не выходит. Подскажите, в чём проблема?

```
fio1 = "Иванов Иван Иванович"
fio1 = fio1.replace(' ', '')
list_fio1 = list(fio1)
list_fio2 = []
for x in list_fio1:
 x.encode()
 list_fio2.append(x)

print(list_fio2)
```

Мне выводит:

`['И', 'в', 'а', 'н', 'о', 'в', 'И', 'в', 'а', 'н', 'И', 'в', 'а', 'н', 'о', 'в', 'и', 'ч']`

Comment: Эта функция `.encode()` **возвращает** байтовое представление строки, сам **x** вызовом `.encode()` не будет изменен

Comment: @gil9red Подскажите, как поступить в этом случае?

Comment: @gil9red с функцией .unicode() то же самое...

Comment: Что конкретно вам нужно получить в результате? Байтовое представление строки в юникоде или список кодов символов?

Comment: Нужно читать документацию и я ведь написал, что она возвращает значение, соответственно, вам нужно это значение получить: `x = x.encode()`

Comment: @insolor список кодов символов

Comment: Тогда в цикле просто `list_fio2.append(ord(x))` делайте. Функция `ord` возвращает код символа.

Comment: `list_fio2 = [ord(x) for x in fio1]`

Comment: @insolor, разве `ord()` работает с *символами*, а не *байтами*?

Comment: @0andriy, с символами: "Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of that character" [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

Answer (score 0):

`.encode()` не изменяет строку, а отдает изменённую.

```
for x in list_fio1:
     list_fio2.append(x.encode())
```

Однако лучше использовать генератор списка. 
`list_fio2 = [x.encode() for x in list_fio1]`

Comment: Это не генератор, а охват, если уж переводить на русский comprehansion.

Answer (score 0):

Для получения unicode кода символа нужно использовать функцию [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord):

```
fio1 = "Иванов Иван Иванович"
fio1 = fio1.replace(' ', '')
list_fio = []
for x in fio1:
   list_fio.append(ord(x))

print(list_fio)
```

Отличие от метода `encode` - `encode` для каждого символа вернет один или несколько байт (тип `bytes`), представляющих данный символ в указанной кодировке. Если кодировка не указана, то будет использована кодировка utf-8 ([документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)). Из utf-8 напрямую unicode код символа не получить, там относительно сложный алгоритм преобразования.

Можно конечно кодировать в байты в кодировке utf-16 (или utf-32 для надежности, чтобы поддерживались символы с кодом больше `0xffff`), потом из байт декодировать в число, но это будет только лишним усложнением. Для сравнения, вот такая конструкция:

```
int.from_bytes('я'.encode('utf-32-le'), 'little')
```

даст тот же результат, что просто `ord('я')`.